# Deleting a row from a MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php

My queries are not getting deleted from the table.  I also want it to return to the first page after deletion.

```
<html>
<title> Queries</title>
<body>
<h1> List of Queries</h1>
<form method=post action="delete7.php"> 
<?php
$ebits = ini_get('error_reporting');
error_reporting($ebits ^ E_NOTICE);// Turns off all the notices &warnings
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());//Connects to the DB
mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error()); //Selects one database
echo "<br />";
$query = "select * from queries ";
$result =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); //sends a unique query to active database on the server
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<th><tr><td> </td><td>Name</td><td>Address</td><td>ContactNo</td><td>Query</td></tr></th>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{ 
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td><input type='checkbox' name='Query[]' value=\"".$row['queryId']."\"> </td>"; 
echo " <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['address'] . "</td><td>" . $row['contactNo'] . "</td><td>" . $row['query'] . "</td>";
echo"</tr>\n";
}  
?>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete"> <br/>  
</form>
</body>
</html>



<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
if (isset($_POST['Delete']))  
{
  foreach ($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox) 
  {
    echo "$checkbox";
    $del = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM queries WHERE queryId=

$checkbox") or die(mysql_error());

    if($del)
    { 
      echo ("Records Deleted"); 
    }   
    else
    {
      echo ("No Way");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query to delete data is wrong. You have `*` in the delete query which is not allowed.

This should be

```
$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM queries WHERE queryId=$checkbox") 
       or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It might help to put the correct query, too: `DELETE FROM queries WHERE queryId=$checkbox` (no `*` after DELETE). Also, if you see code like this, please explain about SQL Injection...

Comment: Konerak, why don't you explain SQL injections yourself? :-)

Comment: Thank you :) :). I just had to remove the star. Can you tell me which coe should i add that the second page returns to first page after deletion

Comment: @teana: you can add this `if($del)
    { 
      header('location:url of the page where you want to redirect');die();
    }`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the star from your query:

```
DELETE FROM queries WHERE queryId = $checkbox;
```

Didn't you get an error message from mysql_error about a syntax error?

---

By the way, you cannot call mysql_error without a valid MySQL connection. This means that this row is strange:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());//Connects to the DB
```

Consider creating your own error message here, like this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect to DB');//Connects to the DB
```